# Android Studio Error:Execution transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

Got following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\TimaMar.android\build-cache\bd5ecf9526c3edbe2d8a73d74135b9a9fcd6533298dfdb7a3103a64cb631ff78\output -> C:\Users\TimaMar\Kizaru\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar: Ошибка в данных (CRC).

Comment: Please read how to ask question before asking anything https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to local.properties and add this :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

and make sure you have  multiDexEnabled true in defaultConfig of your gradle :

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ...
    minSdkVersion ...
    versionCode 1...
    versionName ....
    targetSdkVersion ...

    multiDexEnabled true //important
}
```

Comment: How do you get to this `org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m`?